# MYSQL Order By REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-order-by

I need to search and "order by" by a field whose contents look something like this.

```
32:string1,24:string2,101:string3,1033:string4
```

Pairs are delimited by commas.
Then,

```
sortOrder:string
```

When I know the "string" I want to "order by" the number preceding it (just before the colon).
And, order by that as a number, not a string.*

That is, if I have "string2", I want 24 to be used as the "order by" *number*.

Is this possible with mysqli? If so, can you give an example?

If mysqli cannot do it, should I get the results first then reorder (php is used).
If so, can you offer a solution?

*One issue this may have is the field is text. If it order by a text, then I'd get the order 
1, 100, 111, 2, 200, 5 (not wanted)
instead of
1, 2, 5, 100, 111, 200 (preferred).
Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index()`.  It is a bit tricky, but given your sample data:

```
order by substring_index(substring_index(col, @string, -1), ',', -1) + 0
```

Note that before the `+`, the string will have the colon -- such as `'24:'`.  But MySQL handles that using silent conversion.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion didn't sort on the preceding number. I got, 10, 5, 2, 100, 50. ... I think I found a way by getting the resulting array from mysqli then with some juggling and changing a sort field (in the php array, not the table), re-sorted the array on that sort field.